# How can I define a space without using fixed dimensions?

Tags: css, responsive

First off, I'm new to Overflow, so forgive me if this is in the wrong spot.

Here's my question: I'm learning CSS, and I'm currently styling the html for a simple test page. I need to move some text around so there's a good space between it and some forms (~100px). I've been entering fixed values into the `margin`, like 100px, which works... but is not responsive. If I view the file on a phone or even a different sized monitor, it gets skewed because it's trying to keep the static 100px.

In the past, I've gotten around this problem by using percentages rather than pixels. For example, I set the image `width` to 100% rather than 100px. It always fills the screen, no matter what you view it on. Unfortunately, I can't define a space with percentages.

**How can I define a space without using fixed dimensions, so that it is responsive?**

**Examples:**

- I'm trying to use a large image as the background for a div. The div
  has nothing in it yet, so naturally I only see a thin strip of the
  image. If I set the image dimensions using pixels, it expands the
  div, but is not responsive. If I try using percentages, it remains a thin strip. 100% of the div doesn't change the div width, because it's already at
  100%. (I did later fix this by applying the image as the background of the `body`, but the question remains.
- I have some text 200px below a button. The problem is that I want both the text and the button to remain on top of a background image. If I set the pixel dimensions and the image is resonsive, the text is always 200px below the button, no matter how small the image is. How can I set it so that it's always a certain *percentage* below the button, or from the bottom of the image (whichever is more convenient)?

*Note: I don't know much about js, php, or anything other than CSS and html. If there's another programming language you need to use in your answer, kindly explain it. Thanks!*

Comment: you have to post actual code

Comment: A good question to consider is "percentage of what?" You might try using percentage [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding), as it is relative to the width of its containing block. It might help to show your specific context, what you tried, and where you got stuck.

Comment: Padding and margins can be set with percent values.  You can also use the unit 'em', which is a unit of spacing that scales with the font size.  Try this resource for various CSS elements, which are useful in different situations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length
Example code will go a long way to solving your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

To set a fixed height and width of a div, while being responsive, I use the units vh and vw. For example, to set the height of a div to be 40% of the viewport (viewport is the user's visible area of a web page.), use:
`height = 40vh;`
This way, even if you resize your browser or view it on a different device, it will always render that div to be 40% of the viewport's height.
You can also use other relative units. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp